# next_permutation compare function

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I want to generate all permutation of a `vector< pair<int,int> > v`...using c++ next_permutation such that permutation are generated only basis of `v[i].first` irrespective of the value of `v[i].second`...
example...

```
v.push_back(pair<int,int>(3,600));

v.push_back(pair<int,int>(2,900));

v.push_back(pair<int,int>(2,800));
```

I need following 3 permutation( treating (2,900) and (2,800) as same ).

(2,900) (2,800) (3,600)

(2,900) (3,600) (2,800)

(3,600) (2,900) (2,800)

But instead i get 6 permutations( (2,900) and (2,800) are being treated different )

I know it has to be done by using comparator function in next_permutation....but i am not able to....Pls help how to use comparator function...

here is the code..

```
int main()
{
  vector< pair<int,int> > v;

  v.push_back(pair<int,int>(3,600));
  v.push_back(pair<int,int>(2,900));
  v.push_back(pair<int,int>(2,800));

  sort(v.begin(),v.end());

  do
  {
    for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
    {
      printf("%d %d   ",v[i].first,v[i].second);
    }
    printf("\n");
   }while( next_permutation(v.begin(),v.end()) );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us some code dude.

Comment: Sooo... what comparator functions have you tried?

Comment: i am not able to come up with any comparator function for this...

Comment: @shakim _'i am not able to come up with any comparator function for this'_ No wonder, `pair<int,int>` doesn't provide a default one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::next_permutation` accepts an optional comparator as its last argument.
The function definition [is](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) :

```
template <class BidirectionalIterator, class Compare>
  bool next_permutation (BidirectionalIterator first,
                         BidirectionalIterator last, Compare comp);
```

you could use a custom comparator that compares only the first member of the pair :

```
using namespace std;

struct compareFirstPairMember {
    bool operator()(const pair<int, int>& a, const pair<int, int>& b) const {
        return a.first < b.first;
    }
};
```

Then getting all the permutations (on a sorted vector with the same comparator), is trivial :

```
int main() {

    vector<pair<int, int>> v;
    v.push_back(pair<int,int>(3,600));
    v.push_back(pair<int,int>(2,900));
    v.push_back(pair<int,int>(2,800));

    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compareFirstPairMember());

    do {
        for(auto item : v)
          cout << item.first << " " << item.second << endl;
        cout << endl;
    } while ( std::next_permutation(begin(v), end(v), compareFirstPairMember()));

    return 0;
}
```

**Outputs:**

> 2 900 2 800 3 600
>
> 2 900 3 600 2 800
>
> 3 600 2 800 2 900

Live example [here](http://ideone.com/qLVPr6).

**EDIT:**

In C++11, you can inline the comparison function by using a lambda:

```
std::next_permutation(begin(v), end(v), [](const pair<int, int>& a, const pair<int, int>& b) { return a.first < b.first; })
```

Comment: In C++11, you can use a lambda